# What´s the measure of angle $\angle IMN$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

In a triangle $ABC$, $\hat B=90^\circ$, $AB < BC$, draw the height $BH$
where $M$, $N$ and $I$ are the incenters of $ABH$, $HBC$ and $ABC$.

$\measuredangle BCA=\theta$.

Calculate $\measuredangle IMN$.

My progress ...
Here's a drawing with the relationships I found...
[image]

Comment: @Tim...The answer is in theta function and not numerical

Comment: Please add a/the question also in the text of the post, not only in the title. As it stays, we have an imperative *Calculate $\measuredangle IMN$* in the text, which may seem less polite for some reader. Please give the source of the problem (so that it is clear this is not a current contest problem). "**where** *$M$, $N$ and $I$ are the incenters of...*" is rather "**and construct** *$M$, $N$ and $I$ are the incenters of...*" Please use mathjax in the future for all mathematical symbols - instead of getting them in text form - e.g. `\measuredangle` delivers the symbol $\measuredangle$.

Comment: I just got $\theta$ = $2\measuredangle IMN$, I could be wrong, but please check if you can.

Comment: @dan_fulea..The text of the question is exactly as in the book. The answer being in function of theta is not mentioned, only through the answer in the book. In the reference I always put a faithful copy of the question... so the resolution must be based on this statement, if I am going to modify the text
 does not seem to me to be correct. Interpretation is part of the resolution. In the title I do not imperatively put what is asked. But if there is anything that could be improved, just let me know and I'll fix it in the next questions. Thank you for the hints.. Source: Peruvian Geometry Book

Comment: @Tim...answer: $\angle IMN = \frac{\theta}{2}$..perfect...post your resolution

Comment: Hint: show $\small \triangle MHN\sim\triangle ABC$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $BH$ intersect $MI$ and $MN$ at $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

In two similar triangles, ratio of corresponding sides=ratio of inradii

$\small{\triangle ABH\sim\triangle BCH}\implies\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{GH}{HF}=\frac{MH}{HN}\implies\small{\triangle ABC\sim\triangle MHN}$

Therefore, $\angle HMN=90^\circ-\theta$

$\angle MQP=45^\circ+(90^\circ-\theta)=135^\circ-\theta$

$\angle ABH=\theta, \angle BAD=45^\circ-\frac{\theta}{2}\implies\angle BPM=135^\circ-\frac{\theta}{2}$

Therefore from $\triangle PQM$, $\angle IMN=(135^\circ-\frac{\theta}{2})-(135^\circ-\theta)=\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: Another way:...already demonstrated: $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle MHN \implies \angle MNH = \theta$
$ \triangle AOF: \measuredangle O = 90^o - \frac{\angle{A}}{2}\\ but~ \angle A = 90^ô-\frac{\theta}{2}\implies \angle O = 45^o +\frac{\theta}{2}\\
\triangle MON: \angle IMN = 180^o -(45^o+\frac{\theta}{2})-(135^o-\theta) \\
\therefore \angle IMN = \frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: +1 this is good solution. However you do not need points $P$ and $Q$. Once you establish $\angle HMN = 90-\theta$ using similarity of triangles, note that $\angle MAH = 45 - \theta/2$ and $\angle MHA = 45$. So $\angle HMI = 90 - \theta/2$. $ \therefore \angle IMN = \theta/2$

Answer (score 2):

Extend $CN$ and it intersects $BM$ at $J$. Extend $BM$ and it intersects $AC$ at $K$.

[image]

Given $\angle ABH = \angle ACB = \theta$ and $BK$  bisects $\angle ABH$ so we have,

$CJ \perp BK$ but $BJ$ is also the angle bisector of $\angle BCK$. Hence $J$ is midpoint of $BK$ and circumcenter of right triangle $\triangle BHK$

So, $\angle BHJ = \angle HBJ = \theta/2$

As $JMHN$ is cyclic, $\angle JMN = \angle JHN = 45^\circ + \theta/2$

As $\angle AMB = 135^\circ, \angle IMJ = 45^\circ$

$\therefore \angle IMN = \theta/2$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint: Start with a simple form where triangle is isosceles. Observe that points A, M and I are collinear. Similarly points C, N and I are collinear.In this case $\angle IMN=\angle INM= \frac{\angle BCA}2$. You have to show that $\angle IMN=\frac {\theta}2$ in  all positions of vertex B on the circumcircle. Also $\angle MIN=135^o$ all time.

Answer (score 1):

Yet an other solution chasing angles. Let $2\alpha$ and $2\gamma=\theta$ be the angles in $A$ and respectively $C$, so $90^\circ=2(\alpha+\gamma)$ giving $\alpha+\gamma=45^\circ$.

We draw now the angle bisectors in the mentioned three triangles from the posted problem, and have the picture:

[image: math stackexchange 4265197]

Construct the intersections $M'$ of the angle bisectors $AM$ and $BN$, and $N'$ of the angle bisectors $CN$ and $BM$.

We have $CNN'\perp BN'M$ since in $\Delta CN'B$ we know the angles in $B,C$.
So $NN'$ is a height in $\Delta BMN$. Similarly $MM'$ is also a height. So we have in one breath:
$$
\widehat{IMN}=
\widehat{IBN}=\gamma =\frac 12\theta\ .
$$